# Mass email id duplicate check

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, email, csv

I have a table(email_list) with following columns

id INT (auto increment), email var char, status TINY-INT

User has a form which has only one field from where he can upload csv
csv contains only one column with email ids

csv contains **min 100** and **max 500** email ids.

when user click on upload button

1) I want to check email(s) present in csv are already exist in email_list table

2) check emails are duplicate in csv itself or not

If no duplicates found **then only** I can insert all email ids in table

If duplicates found **I want to display error message with list of emails** 
which are exist in email_list table 
and also if any email is duplicate itself in csv.

I am using code igniter and mysql

How I can achieve this?

What if email_list table has 5000+ rows and uploading csv contains 500 email ids

- INSERT IGNORE is not applicable (If no duplicates found then only I can insert all email ids in table)

comparison operation will took so much time

Please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

Check the database for the IDs first:

```
SELECT email
FROM email_list
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

You can populate the list of IDs before the query.

```
$user_ids = array();
foreach($users as $user) {
    $user_ids[] = $user->id;
}

// Do query here

if(count($res) > 0) {
    foreach($res as $row) {
        echo "Duplicate email: {$row->email}";
    }
} else {
    // Do insert
}
```

Comment: inserting csv email ids in temp table and then using IN query performing comparison operation will take so much time  and never use IN operator when it contains near 100 ids its bad practice bcoz IN query actually look like this WHERE id = 1 or id = 2 or id = 3 ......